# can't restore windows 7 to a hard drive even tho the computer can find the hdd

Tags: windows-7, system-restore, windows-7-backup, windows-7-restore

So in Windows 7 / System Recovery Options I click on System Image Recovery. The image is loaded from a DVD (last disc of the DVD per the instructions) and I can see the HDD when I click on the "Exclude disks..." button on the "Choose additional restore options" dialog. Here's a picture of what I see:

[image]

So the hard drive exists and the OS sees it.

But...  from the dialog in the screenshot, if I click "OK", then "Next >", "Finish" and "Yes" (for the "All disks to be restored will be formatted" confirmation) I get a "The system image restore failed" error. Here's a picture:

[image]

Here's what the "Details" dialog says:

[image]

Problem is...  none of those explanations apply! I didn't exclude the disk, it's not a USB stick. Any ideas?

`diskpart` / `list disk` shows the disk, I can write to it when I plug it into another computer via a USB3 <-> SATA adapter, etc.

The computer I'm trying to do the restore on is an ASUS U52F. It came with a 640GB HDD but for what I'm going to be using the computer for I don't need an HDD that big so it's my intention to move the OS to a smaller HDD and repurpose the larger one.

Comment: What imaging program did you use - Windows imaging (big mistake) or one of the OEM programs (much better).

Comment: The image cannot be stored on the same disk you wish to restore to.

Comment: It seems like it ought to be able to operate in situ. Like how you don't have an entire youtube video downloaded before you watch it - you can watch it as it downloads. In any event, I did try to plug a 1TB HDD in via USB3 and it still wouldn't work. `diskpart` `list part` saw both disks and they both had plenty of space per http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-2404649/bytes-free-showing-diskpart.html#14744813 but it just didn't work. I just wound up using Acronis True Image. It's disappointing that the built-in product is so bad. If it's gonna be this bad why include it at all?